# APA format bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

Hello to the whole community, I have a query regarding changing the format of the bibliography and citations of this work in APA format, when I have made the change with "STYLE=APA", I get everything moved, if someone knows perhaps how to do the I would greatly appreciate the change, I leave the link of the work
[overleaf work](https://www.overleaf.com/1789624128ftjxvnmhvvmg)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Questions posted here should be self-contained.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Comment: I used "style =apa" but the quotes are repeated, and I don't know how to change it

Comment: what quotes? By the way you are loading` \addbibresource{referencias.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}` twice.

Comment: In you system save the main file with a new name and run pdflatex + biber + pdflatex + pdfaltex. Overleaf will do it automatically.